# How to install pgAdmin3 in CentOS6?

Tags: centos, centos6, postgresql

I need to install pgAdmin3 in CentOS6 but I'm getting dependencies errors.

```
[root@andre tmp]# rpm -ivh --aid pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
warning: pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 0608b895: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_baseu-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8.5)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_baseu_net-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_baseu_net-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_html-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_html-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_ogl-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_ogl-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_stc-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_stc-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8.so.0()(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
libwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8.so.0(WXU_2.8)(64bit) is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
wxGTK is needed by pgadmin3-1.12.2-2.el6.x86_64
```

There is a way to install this RPM with dependencies or I have to install this dependencies by hand one by one?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe your CentOS to [PostgreSQL yum repository](http://yum.pgrpms.org/), which has packages for pgAdmin3 available as well. You can then install pgAdmin and receive updates to it via yum, such as you usually do with CentOS.